# Pass and get value from functions running in multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am trying to run my program in parallel for five thread. I am using the run function of the runnable interface. This is what my code looks like right now:

```
class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
private Thread t;
private String val;

RunnableDemo(int a, int b){
   val1=a;
   val2=b;
}
public void run () 
{
  int sum =0;
  sum= val1 + val2;
}
public void start ()
{
  if (t == null)
  {  
     t = new Thread (this, val1, val2);
     t.start ();
  }
}
}

 public class Parallel_execution {
 public static void main(String args[]) {  
  int x=2
  int i=0;
  for (i=0;i<5; i++){
      RunnableDemo R = new RunnableDemo(x,i);
      R.start();
      }
   }
   }
```

I want to get the values of the sum for all threads and use it again in some other function. How does the function running in the thread return values? How do I access those values?

Comment: take `sum` as property of class and initialize computed value in run method, use join to wait for all thread to compute `sum` and then loop through all Threads and `getSum()`

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity, Touched up grammar.

Answer (score 0):

the `run()` method of `runnable` interface does not return something it's a `void`, but you can define the `sum` variable outside the method:

```
class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
/...
int sum =0;
//public getter and setter (getSum,setSum)
public void run () 
{
  sum= val1 + val2;
}
//...
}
```

and now you can simply access it:

```
 public class Parallel_execution {
 public static void main(String args[]) {  
  int x=2
  int i=0;
  for (i=0;i<5; i++){
      RunnableDemo R = new RunnableDemo(x,i);
      R.start();
      System.out.println(R.getSum());
      }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Your example shows a call to `RunnableDemo.start()` but it doesn't show any such method declared.  Wonder if you meant to say `new Thread(new RunnableDemo()).start()`.

Comment: Also, assuming that `R.start()` is supposed to start a thread, your `main()` method then immediately looks for the value without first waiting for the thread to compute it.

Comment: just look at question, I didn't bring all code in answer, (`//...`), I just bring changes

Comment: Right you are.  My comment about not waiting for the threads to compute results still stands though.  @PriyalJain Whenver threads need to communicate with one another, they must be synchronized.  In this case, since the run() method does not loop, the main() routine can synchronize with the worker threads by `join()`ing each thread before looking at the result that the thread computed.

Comment: of course in case of Synchronization and some other concepts in multi threading in java, the code in question has many problems, but I thought this is a practice and the question owner is not using them in this step (as he/she told: _I'm new in Java_) I just didn't want to make it a little more dificult